# Start program without focus

Tags: linux-mint, window-focus

How can I start a program from a python script without its window becoming focused?  Specifically, I'm using ImageMagick's `display`.

Environment: Linux Mint 17, Cinnamon 2.2.16

Comment: check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585625/use-terminal-to-display-image-without-losing-focus